# TinyMCE 5.x ResizeEditor-Event for manual resize?

Tags: tinymce-5

Event "ResizeEditor" https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/

> Fired when the editor is resized, either by the resize handles or the
>   auto-resize plugin.

Is there a way to check if the editor size was changed by the user via resize icon (right-bottom)?
I need to know when a user changes the size by hand(mouse) and only then.